# Write file in java to src directory

Tags: java, file

I am writing a few files with test results with Java, that I want to check into source control.

The closest method I have found to do this is:

```
 myclass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath())
```

Which will write the file to the class directory in the build.

Is there a trick/quick way that I could write the file to the path that the class is in in the development src folder, rather than the build directory?

Comment: There's nothing that says the source directory even exists.  You have to make assumptions about your development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better pass path to src dir thru system property. You can read it by `System.getProperty("name")` and pass to your program by `-Dname=value` command line argument.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `src` is under your project folder you can do this:

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "\\src\\" + this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
```

Comment: How do you know that that's where the source is?

Comment: well i don't. Thus the "assuming" part :P